# How to create a joinable semaphore in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, semaphore, python-multithreading

In some use-cases i need to wait for all already created threads to finish and make some decisions based on their results and see whether we need to move further or not - without `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()`.

i implemented it like this:

```
from threading import BoundedSemaphore, Event


class JoinSemaphore(BoundedSemaphore):
    def __init__(self, value=1):
        super().__init__(value)
        self._empty = Event()

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        if self._value < self._initial_value:
            self._empty.wait(timeout)

    def release(self):
        with self._cond:
            if self._value >= self._initial_value:
                raise ValueError("Semaphore released too many times")
            elif self._value == self._initial_value - 1:
                self._empty.set()

            self._value += 1
            self._cond.notify()

    def acquired(self):
        with self._cond:
            return self._initial_value - self._value
```

Here i compute `self._value < self._initial_value` without any guard and it has risk.
when i write the join() function like bellow to prevent unwanted changes while i'm computing `self._value < self._initial_value` i will face a deadlock when the main-thread joins on the semaphore and at this point other thread and not acquire `release()` lock because main thread already accrued it, but main thread still waiting for other threads. so this implementation is not correct.

```
    def join(self, timeout=None):
        with self._cond:
            if self._value < self._initial_value:
                self._empty.wait(timeout)
```

In third implementation i cannot guarantee that when i want to `wait()` for `_empty` event, other threads wouldn't have possibly submit their results and release the lock.

```
    def join(self, timeout=None):
        with self._cond:
            if self._value == self._initial_value:
                return
        self._empty.wait(timeout)
```

the Question is:

How can i compute `self._value < self._initial_value` correctly using lock and wait for `_empty` event and release the lock before waiting on it to avoid deadlock?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you just wrap the counter reading and writing operations with their own `threading.Lock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way i found for this problem, i wanted to inherit from base Semaphore class but couldn't find an easy solution to fix the problem, so i decided to edit the base BoundSemaphore class:

```
from threading import Event, Condition, Lock
from time import monotonic as _time


class JoinSemaphore:

    def __init__(self, value=1):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("semaphore initial value must be >= 0")
        self._cond = Condition(Lock())
        self._value = value
        self._initial_value = value
        self._empty = Event()
        self._empty.set()

    def acquire(self, blocking=True, timeout=None):
        if not blocking and timeout is not None:
            raise ValueError("can't specify timeout for non-blocking acquire")
        rc = False
        endtime = None
        with self._cond:
            while self._value == 0:
                if not blocking:
                    break
                if timeout is not None:
                    if endtime is None:
                        endtime = _time() + timeout
                    else:
                        timeout = endtime - _time()
                        if timeout <= 0:
                            break
                self._cond.wait(timeout)
            else:
                self._empty.clear()
                self._value -= 1
                rc = True
        return rc

    __enter__ = acquire

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self._empty.wait(timeout)

    def release(self):
        with self._cond:
            if self._value >= self._initial_value:
                raise ValueError("Semaphore released too many times")
            elif self._value == self._initial_value - 1:
                self._empty.set()

            self._value += 1
            self._cond.notify()

    def acquired(self):
        with self._cond:
            return self._initial_value - self._value
```

diffs are:

```
class JoinSemaphore:

    def __init__(self, value=1):
        ...
        self._empty = Event()
        self._empty.set()

    def acquire(self, blocking=True, timeout=None):
        ...
        with self._cond:
            while ...:
        ...
            else:
                self._empty.clear()
        ...

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self._empty.wait(timeout)

    def release(self):
        ...
            elif self._value == self._initial_value - 1:
                self._empty.set()
        ...

    def acquired(self):
        with self._cond:
            return self._initial_value - self._value
```